# Value not found

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have the following Scala code

```
    package basic

import org.scalatest.FlatSpec
import org.scalatest._
import com.bosch.test.FilterCol._
import org.apache.spark
import org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame
import org.apache.spark.sql._

class FilterColScalaTest extends FlatSpec with Matchers with SparkSessionTestWrapper {

  val dfInput = spark.createDataFrame(example)
  val actualDF = dfInput.filterColumns()

}
object FilterColScalaTest {
  def main(args:Array[String]): Unit = {
    println("Hello World")
  }
}
case class phoneNumbers(c1: String, c2: String, c3: String, c4: String, c5: String)
{

  val example = Seq(
    phoneNumbers("(123)-456-7890", "123-456-7890", "(123)-456-789", null, "(123)456-7890"),
    phoneNumbers("(123)-456-7890", "123-4567890", "(123)-456-7890", "(123)-456-7890", null),
    phoneNumbers("(123)-456-7890", "1234567890", "(123)-456-7890", "(123)-456-7890", null)
  )




}
```

This is the error I get. I am new to Scala and don't understand why this is an issue. Am I missing some Maven libraries?

```
  not found : value example
```

I tried adding the case class phonenumbers outside the class declaration. But it does not understand the createdataframe and filtercolumn functions.

Comment: From the error, you need to implement 4 methods:
convertEquivalenceToAToBConstraint, convertEquivalenceToBToAConstraint, lowPriorityTypeCheckedConstraint and typeCheckedConstraint.

Comment: @VladislavKievski I am not using any of those methods. Do you need any further information?

Comment: Could you show all file?

Comment: You have to define case class out of FilterColScalaTest  scope. Move declaration out of the class.

Comment: @VladislavKievski i have added the complete code. Filtercolumns is a method in a different file.

Comment: @PrateekPrateek how can i access the case class variable example in my other class?

Comment: @VladislavKievski I had to change the question. Prateek's thing worked, I am not sure how access the value though. Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To fix your issue you need to write something like this:

```
package basic

import org.scalatest.FlatSpec
import org.scalatest._
import com.bosch.test.FilterCol._
import org.apache.spark
import org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame
import org.apache.spark.sql._

class FilterColScalaTest extends FlatSpec with Matchers with SparkSessionTestWrapper {

  val example = Seq(
    phoneNumbers("(123)-456-7890", "123-456-7890", "(123)-456-789", null, "(123)456-7890"),
    phoneNumbers("(123)-456-7890", "123-4567890", "(123)-456-7890", "(123)-456-7890", null),
    phoneNumbers("(123)-456-7890", "1234567890", "(123)-456-7890", "(123)-456-7890", null)
  )

  val dfInput = spark.createDataFrame(example)
  val actualDF = dfInput.filterColumns()

}
object FilterColScalaTest {
  def main(args:Array[String]): Unit = {
    println("Hello World")
  }
}
case class phoneNumbers(c1: String, c2: String, c3: String, c4: String, c5: String)
```

Some recommendations by style:

First of all, by scala convention classes should be called from Upper case, so use should call your class like *PhoneNumbers*.

Also, I recommend to call it as *PhoneNumber and the have:

```
val phoneNumbers = Vector(PhoneNumber("(123)-456-7890"), PhoneNumber("123-456-7890"))
```

Comment: Could you provide dependencies that you use?